# Mouse Pointer Glitch when using Dual Monitors, Win 8.1, Excel 2013, and VBA, Visual Studio. Cursor Drifts

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, mouse, vba, visual-studio-2013

I have been using Windows 8.1 and Excel 2013 and I've been writing a lot of VB for Excel. Also I've been using Visual Studio 2013 on some projects I'm working on. I've searched for this answer and found nothing so far.

**The problem** is that every so often, the **cursor will drift  .25" off to the left** of the Mouse Pointer and stay there relative to the actual position.  It will usually do this with a glitch in the image for the pointer as well.  So when you click on some text, the cursor appears 3-4 characters out of position to the left.  This is while I'm editing code not in MY applications themselves.

**System specs**

- Windows 8.1
- Core 2 Duo Q8400 2.66 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- Dual Monitor - [1280 x 768] x [1280x1024]
- Graphics: Radeon HD 5700
- Software:  Excel in one window [1280 x 1024] with Editor in the [1280x768]
  or Visual Studio by itself with multiple windows spread across both screens.

The glitch has happened to me when debugging in Visual Studio, using Intellitrace in one screen and Visual Studio in the other.  It regularly occurs using Excel and VBA though.  If memory serves, it's usually associated with a clipboard copy/paste of text.  I can't say for sure though because it's not a regular occurance.

It will create a series of lines, instead of an arrow, or a cursor, it's a bunch of glitchy dashes that take up two rows worth of text vertically and are off by roughly .25".

The graphical glitch will vary in what kind of glitch it is, and I can't reproduce it on demand.

A re-boot solves it.  I just can't afford to be shutting my computer down once every 1.5 hours or so.  Has anyone had any issues with this?  Any ideas are welcome, as this does cost me a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

If I get a glitch to occur, I will post a screenshot, but the screencap software doesn't see the glitch.  I will have to take a snapshot with a camera. (maybe that's a clue)

Comment: I assume your drivers are up to date with the original manufacturer's drivers (not MS drivers)

Comment: Yes. Updated drivers

Comment: Do you have a spare graphics card you can try/borrow

Comment: Actually, yes.  I have a system just like this.  Good idea.  I'll report with the results.  Since it's intermittent, I might not know right away.